# Real path of an included script

Tags: shell-script

Can an included script know if it's being included and get its real path ?

Suppose a script called `sub.sh` that check if the user has access to the script group, before to run its main logic:

```
#...
mypath=`realpath -e $0`
#if blablabla ... check mypath against user groups...
#
#...
```

The above script can be included in another one, like so:

```
#...
. sub.sh
#...
```

But, as it is being included by another script, the check-up runs against the caller script, which isn't the desired effect.

Comment: You might be able to check `$0`, though that's a bit unreliable (the calling program can set it to whatever it wants). When you're run from the shell, though, `$0` is set to the name of what you typed on the command line; if it's `sub.sh`, you were run directly, and if not, you were sourced.

Comment: Did you see the line "mypath=`realpath -e $0`" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `BASH_SOURCE` array (in bash).

Example:

**sourcee.bs**

```
fun(){
    echo "$0"
    echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
}
```

**sourcer.bs**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$0"
echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
source sourcee.bs
fun
```

**testrun**

```
$ ./sourcer.bs
./sourcer.bs
./sourcer.bs
./sourcer.bs
sourcee.bs    #Or the full path if it's in PATH instead of the PWD
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `$0` in ZShell:

```
% echo 'set | grep -a harglebargle' > harglebargle
% source harglebargle                             
0=harglebargle
%
```

(This appears true even if one tries the `ARGV0=... source ...` trick.)

So, for the full path:

```
% echo 'echo $0:a' > fullpath
% source fullpath
/home/jmates/tmp/fullpath
%
```